# PHP regexp: Replace a piece of URL in text string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Please help with understanding php regular expressions. Have this string:

```
<a href="/kop/product/acer-timeline-5810tg-944g50mi" class="imagecache imagecache-product_list imagecache-linked imagecache-product_list_linked"><img src="http://localhost/kop/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/Acer-Timeline-1.jpg" alt="Acer As Timeline 5810TG-944G50Mi" title="Acer As Timeline 5810TG-944G50Mi" class="imagecache imagecache-product_list" width="100" height="100" /></a>
```

I need to replace **product_list** that situated between **imagecache/** and **/SOME_TEXT** within `<img>` tag, with, for example  `product_list_replaced`

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to do that is easier to use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), you can do it this way:

```
$text = '<a href="/kop/product/acer-timeline-5810tg-944g50mi" class="imagecache imagecache-product_list imagecache-linked imagecache-product_list_linked"><img src="http://localhost/kop/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/Acer-Timeline-1.jpg" alt="Acer As Timeline 5810TG-944G50Mi" title="Acer As Timeline 5810TG-944G50Mi" class="imagecache imagecache-product_list" width="100" height="100" /></a>';

$new = '<img>product_list_replaced</img>';
$match = 'imagecache/';

$newstr= str_replace($match, $replace, $text);
```

If you are interested in regular expresions take a look of [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

HTH!